# swift how to embed one app to another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am intern student who working mobile applications on swift. I created an app for company and I need to embed my app to other partner firm's app. I look some solutions on stackoverflow but they were not clear, Should I use target file? How to embed one app to another app?

Thanks for all help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embedding one app to another isn't quiet right definition. What you are looking for is a Dynamic Framework. You can add a new Dynamic Framework target to your partner's app and move all the functionality and resources you need from your app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2435/_index.html

> A framework is a hierarchical directory that encapsulates a dynamic library, header files, and resources, such as storyboards, image files, and localized strings, into a single package. Apps using frameworks need to embed the framework in the app's bundle.

In case if you only want to allow the user to navigate from one app to another, you should use iOS Deep Linking mechanism. There are many third party, ready to use solutions for that, like Branch.

https://branch.io/

This can be usefull as well:

https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/

Comment: Hello @vahanbabayan, in my case, for instance when user uses partner firm's app and there will be small square, when user clicked this square, their app allows user to come my apps and do all the things. In this case, should I use dynamic framework?

Comment: No, I didn't get you right. In that case you should use iOS Deep Linking mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by defining a URL schema for your app so that the partner's app can point to.

Here is a tutorial that you need
http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-deep-linking-in-swift/